# Find the sum of the power series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+2)!}{(2!)(n!)}x^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find the sum of the power series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+2)!}{(2!)(n!)}x^n$

frist I use $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$$

and multiple two side by $x^2$

can get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+2} = \frac{x^3}{1-x}$$

then diff each side two times

we can obtain $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)x^n= \frac{2x^3-6x^2+6x}{(1-x)^3}$$

but not the solution  $=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$

Comment: use Newton's binomial theorem

Comment: the result should be $$-\frac{x \left(x^2-3 x+3\right)}{(x-1)^3}$$

Comment: You should be using $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+2}=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)}$ then differentiate and which will get you $\frac{2x-x^2}{(1-x)^2}=n+2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}$ then differentiate again and you'll get your final answer by finally diving by 2.

Comment: thanks,I found that this question is wrong, n is start from zero.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from zero,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+2)!}{(2!)(n!)}x^n
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^n\\
&=\frac1{x^2}(1-x)^{-3}\\
\end{array}
$

by the generalized binomial theorem
(since
$\binom{-n}{k}
=(-1)^n \binom{n+k-1}{k}
$).